# running web api project in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013

I have a web api project which I can run it correctly in the VS 2012 but when I open the project and run the project, every thing working correctly (other asp .net mvc and other class libraries in the same solution) but I can't run the web api project in VS 2013, it bringing up an error and fails to run but no error show in the errors list.

NOTE:This project is running correctly in the VS 2012, is there any problem or any changes which I must make before running the project?

Answer (score 1):

Try applying update1  for visual studio and than open your project.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=41650